# pass the path of a file which is obtained by file picker to to a variable and use as input for cv2.imread but it seems to not pass anything

Tags: python, class, opencv

how do i access the path of a png file from main.py in recent.py?

I take the file path from here (path is required in recent.py)

main.py

```
def open_dialog_box(self):
        global path
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        path = filename[0]
        print(path)
        os.system('python recent.py')
```

recent.py

```
paintWindow =cv2.imread("path obtained from file picker")
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#argument-passing

Comment: Thus, in your main.py: `os.system(f'python recent.py "{path}"')` (or better yet, use `subprocess.call(['python', 'recent.py', path])`) then in your recent.py: `cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])`.